# Even intersect of neighbors of even vertices with even degree

Tags: graph-theory

> Given a graph such that there are an even number of vertices and each vertex has an even degree, prove or disprove that there must exist two vertices such that the intersect of their neighbors has even cardinality.

Comment: @Mike Pierce I've tried induction on the number of vertices, but I was unable to find a way to apply the hypothesis, since any way of reducing the graph to the size in the hypothesis wouldn't guarantee even degree of every vertex.  Additionally, I tried direct proof, and eliminated the case of there being two vertices such that they have no common neighbors, since then their common is 0 which is even, so now I am at there being at least one common neighbor for every pair of vertices, but I cannot think of how to proceed.